# Displaying build number in a separate jsp or html page?

Tags: java, maven, hudson

I am using Hudson for the continuous integration. I am using Maven. mine is a web application. it builds  a war. I want to display build number. build number can be included in war using maven-war plugin as hudson supports an environment variable BUILD_NUMBER. build number will be available in manifest file. my requirement is i need to retrieve the build number from manifest file and show in  a jsp/html file. How can i achieve it ? Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1940732/256618

Answer (score 1):

You can pass build number as command line argument when doing maven build.
For example:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -DciVersion=appversion.1
```

where **appversion.1** is generated by your CI tool.
You can create a file in resources say **version.txt** with following content.

```
   build.version=${ciVersion}
```

In pom.xml you can specify version as

```
<version>${ciVersion}</version>
```

Also in POM add resource filtering,  see [Resource pulgin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), that susbtitute your version in version.txt and will copy file into final build file.

Now, you can read this file in your JSP/class to get the version.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manifest can be tricky, given that there may be lots of loaded JARs, each with its  own manifest. Perhaps you could do something like described [here](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/how-to-add-a-version-number-to-your-maven-webapp-482.html)?

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for your reply. can i use <display_version>${BUILD_NUMBER}</display_version> to access in jsp? Please help me..

Comment: Yes, what happens is that Maven replaces the property ${BUILD_NUMBER} with the actual value (when creating the WAR).